# How do I bind a google maps geocoder.geocode() callback function

Tags: javascript, google-maps, backbone.js

I have a view that contains a google map accessible via *this.map* within the view scope.  All is well in the world.

Next I want to update the map position via events in my view.  To do this I take text input, use google.maps.Geocoder.geocode(), then update the position via:

setMapLocation: function (location) {

```
    _.bind(this.setMapLocationCallback, this);

    console.log(this);

    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    geocoder.geocode({'address': location}, this.setMapLocationCallback);

},
```

The *console.log(this)* here shows me the scope of the view, with *this.map* properly accessible.  Notice that I explicitly bind the callback to this here.  Here's the callback:

```
setMapLocationCallback: function (results, status) {

    console.log('this in the callback');
    console.log(this);

    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        this.map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: this.map,
            position: results[0].geometry.location
        });
        this.mapCanvas.css({visibility: 'visibile'});
    } else {
        this.mapCanvas.css({visibility: 'hidden'});
    }
},
```

The problems is that inside the callback *console.log(this)* shows that *this* is scoped to the Window object *even though I bound it explicitly* to the view object's this scope.

I need to access this.map in the callback because I may have more than one map on a page and need to distinguish which one I'm talking about.

How do I bind this callback to the proper scope?  or, is there a better way to do this?

I'm using backbonejs and underscorejs, but this should be a fairly generic problem.

Thanks in advance,
David

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try changing

```
 geocoder.geocode({'address': location}, this.setMapLocationCallback);
```

using `call()`, so you can change the scope of `this` inside `setMapLocationCallback`

```
 var _this = this;
 geocoder.geocode({'address': location}, function(result, status) {
     _this.setMapLocationCallback.call(_this, result, status);
 });
```

[MDN Documentation about call() function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call)

Comment: That did the trick!  Thank you sir!  I've been hearing rumors about this sort of thing being handled by 'intuition' syntax in upcoming versions of js.  Looking forward to seeing how that plays out.

Comment: Meanwhile in ECMAScript 5 they invented the [bind()](https://caniuse.com/mdn-javascript_builtins_function_bind) method exactly for this case: You call it on a function 
 and it creates a new function where 'this' has the value you pass to bind(). It saves you the variable _this and the wrapper function around the actual callback setMapLocationCallback. The whole thing here would just become `geocoder.geocode({'address': location}, this.setMapLocationCallback.bind(this));`

Comment: The code in the question doesn't work because geocode only remembers the function it should call but not its scope (the this value). Even though you give `this.setMapLocationCallback`, it only remembers setMapLocationCallback. Some APIs therefore accept an extra scope parameter. And in the meantime `bind()` was invented to pass a function together with its scope.